# Question on Firebase Authentication SHA1 for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to android and I'm working on a project with some friends that includes a google signup/login page. I have configured the SHA1 on my pc and project setting on firebase and the authentication works great, but when I push the changes to git for my friends to see they can't authenticate with google because their SHA1 key on their signupReport is different and they need to configure it from the start to work for them. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You will either have to add everyone's SHA-1 to the project, or make everyone sign with the same debug key with the same SHA-1.

Comment: just create new SHA1 from ur frend system and add to google and download new google-json file and past in ur project thats it :)

Comment: Yes that would actually work, but it just seems tiresome to get all the keys from all the people if the team is large. Thank you :)